# how to display json in d3 over leaflet.js in React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm struggling to display some json data onto my Leaflet map in react. I'm using leaflet-react to run the map generation. I can't find a decent tutorial to help me through this. My current set up is below;

```
const MapComponent = () => {
return (
        <>
            <MapContainer
                center={[mapSettings.latitude, mapSettings.longitude]}
                zoom={mapSettings.zoom}
                minZoom={6}
                scrollWheelZoom={true}
                zoomControl={false}
                style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}
                maxBounds={[
                    [58.619777025081675, -10.437011718750002],
                    [49.66762782262194, 3.3618164062500004],
                ]}
            >
                <LayerGroup>
                    <D3Layer></D3Layer>
                </LayerGroup>
                <MyMapEvents />
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                />
                
                <NavBar mapZoom={mapSettings.zoom} activeNav={activeNav} navClick={navClick} show={show} />
                <Overlay show={show} />
            </MapContainer>
        </>
    );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

I want to then put the D3 code into the D3Layer component.

At the moment the component returns a h1 tag with hello however this is hidden behind the map. If someone can get something basic working, even if just getting my basics set up to display something basic like a square i'm sure I can figure the importing of the json

Thanks

Comment: @ Chris Bull. Please have a look at my answer and let me know if it solves your issue

Comment: @kboul - Thanks for replying. I'm temporarily moved onto the back end of the app for the time being but will be back on this soon and will try to implement your advice. Do you think the scaffolding I'm implementing here looks sensible? Also, do you think d3 is necessary for this if you are using leaflet to implement d3 transformation? I thought d3 was acting separately to leaflet and didn't rely on it

Comment: If you want to display only geojson you do not need it, but if you want to leverage some other useful functionalities d3 offers you should use it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9211665) of importing a square using `d3` library adapted in `react` and `react-leaflet` by a creating a custom component as you did and include example's code inside a useEffect.

Install `d3`libray and `d3-geo` libray.

In this example I imported directly the json from a file but you can fetch it also using `d3.json`

```
import L from "leaflet";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as d3Geo from "d3-geo";

import geoShape from "./rectangle.json";
```

...

```
function D3Layer() {
     const map = useMap();

     useEffect(() => {
        const svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg");
        const g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");
    
        //  create a d3.geo.path to convert GeoJSON to SVG
        const transform = d3Geo.geoTransform({
           point: projectPoint
        }),
        path = d3Geo.geoPath().projection(transform);
    
          // create path elements for each of the features
        const d3_features = g
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(geoShape.features)
          .enter()
          .append("path");
    
        map.on("viewreset", reset);
    
        reset();
    
        // fit the SVG element to leaflet's map layer
        function reset() {
          const bounds = path.bounds(geoShape);
    
          const topLeft = bounds[0],
            bottomRight = bounds[1];
    
          svg
            .attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
            .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
            .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
            .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");
    
          g.attr(
            "transform",
            "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")"
          );
    
            // initialize the path data
            d3_features
              .attr("d", path)
              .style("fill-opacity", 0.7)
              .attr("fill", "blue");
          }
    
          // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
          function projectPoint(x, y) {
            var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
            this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
          }
        }, []);
        return null;
 }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-display-json-in-d3-over-leafletjs-in-react-leaflet-v3x-q22ur?file=/src/MapComponent.jsx:154-279)